# Creating a Table with Grouping using Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following data in a database

```
salesperson_id   | item      |   value  
1                   112         100
1                   199         100
2                   155         50
```

this is stored in a array as so

```
[  
  {  
  "salesperson_id":"1",
  "ITEM":"112",
  "TOTAL":100
  },
{  
  "salesperson_id":"1",
  "ITEM":"199",
  "TOTAL":100 
},
{  
  "salesperson_id":"2",
  "ITEM":"155",
  "TOTAL":50
}
]
```

using laravel blade how would i get the data to display similar to below

```
|Sales Person - 1 |
                  | ITEM   |  value |
                    112       100
                    199       100
                                      total £200
 | Sales Person 2 | 
                  | ITEM   |  value |
                    155         50    
                                     total £50
```

I can print each line to a table row but i want to change it to the above grouping, it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction, i'm not looking for the code to be done for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for [`Collection::groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-groupby)

```
<table>
    @foreach($data->groupBy('salesperson_id') as $salesperson)
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="{{ count($salesperson)+1 }}">{{ $salesperson[0]['salesperson_id] }}</td>
            @foreach($salesperson as $item)
                <td>{{ $item['ITEM'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item['TOTAL'] }}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total: £ {{ $salesperson->sum('TOTAL') }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Just make sure `$data` is passed to your view as a collection instead of as a plain array.